# interrupted the C partition diskpart format, now C,D and E partitions have been combined

Tags: partitioning, cmd.exe, diskpart

My HDD has 500GB storage, it had three partitions ie C,D and E. While formatting C drive using DISKPART, I pressed ctrl + C for some reason. Now C, D and E partitions are not being shown, instead a single 495gb partition is being shown with RAW format. 
My D and E drives had some important data that I dont want to loose, so what is the best method to recover these drives? 
P.S: I can only access command line, since the windows got corrupted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my data?](http://superuser.com/questions/539744/how-do-i-recover-my-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use one of the recovery tools in Hiren's boot cd such as Raw Copy. See more info on the latest Hiren's Boot CD [here](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd). To download it just search it up quickly in google.
This CD is basically a compilation of tools that can be started from CD, meaning you don't need Windows for it. Luckily for you problem.

1. Start your computer and get to BIOS ([How to Enter your PCs BIOS](http://www.pcworld.com/article/241032/how_to_enter_your_pcs_bios.html)
2. Change the boot order so that your CD gets loaded first.
3. Then put in Hiren's Boot CD and restart your computer.
4. Start the tool and recover your data

OR for step 4 you could also load the mini Windows XP that is within the boot cd, there you could basically just copy everything from your drive to f.e. an external one.

Comment: Hi RnBandCrunk!
That sounds like a good solution. I'll definitely try it and rate your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much RnBandCrunk :)

Answer (score 0):

I think to backup your data you can live boot from a GNU/Linux DVD or USB like Ubuntu.
To download Ubuntu: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop.
To create boot able USB:http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
You can burn a dvd using any dvd burning software.

After live booting into the Ubuntu go to Files and in the left panel you will see your hdd click it to mount and now you can copy your data to some external storage device.

Do comment if you need any help.

Comment: Hi Rahul!
Thanks for answering my question. I personally don't think that live Ubuntu will show me the partitions I had before, since the entire HDD is in RAW format. But still I'll give it a shot, since I cant think of any other solution :)

Comment: You are welcome.You might be right but i have tried this method multiple times on USB's and usually it works pretty well and if I pulgin the same USB to a Window's computer,Windows directly asks me to format the drive to use it.So,I think you must give it a shot before trying something else.