# Hdd recovery - I/O error

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

The system (win 10) froze on shutting down and I had to turn it off by force. From that moment on there has not been any way to access the drive (a 320gb SATA Maxtor). I would like to recover the data if possible. Up until now, I have had no luck accessing the drive.

Here the drive specs:

[image]

The first few times after the failure the driver was still able to run win 10 recovery tools menu but, aside from being slower than the norm, every tool I tried have been of no use: each one of them gave me back either i/o error or disk write protected. I tried with CHKDSK from cmd but it saw the drive as RAW.

This is what I receive every time I now turn on the pc and choose to boot the drive.

[image]

I tried with several other recovery software. Most of which simply didn't detect it or gave back an i/o error.  One of those or maybe the only one able to scout the sectors is GetDataBack.
These are some of the errors it was giving.

[image]
[image]

Based on the type of errors I showed would you advice a PCB swap?

Comment: Based on the errors you are getting, the HDD is in pretty bad shape, you might consider sending it to a service to recover the data.  There are likely mechanical problems with the drive.  Consumer level data recovery is all nearly identical.  Some HDD problems simply cannot be fixed by the end user and require specialized hardware.  The errors indicate the drive is encountering an error every 64 sectors.  The fact the drive behavior got worst is an indication of a hard failure, a data recovery service, MIGHT be able to transplant the HDD platters into another drive.

Comment: Based on the Windows XP on the label, the size of the HDD, and the manufacturer.  You are looking at an extremely old HDD (more than a decade).  Unless the data is extremely valuable it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover my data?](https://superuser.com/questions/539744/how-do-i-recover-my-data)

Comment: With problems such as this it is important to decide early on if the data is worth the cost of professional data recovery. It is possible to literally recover a drive to death. Repeated recovery attempts can damage the drive to such an extent that even professional data recovery can do nothing. It appears you are well on your way to that point, if it is not already too late.

Comment: Yes, the drive is more than a decade old. Even the brand name doesn't exist anymore, it has merged with Seagate.